# Swagger 2.0, Can't add Example name

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I'm using Swagger 2.0 and adding examples to GET and POST methods. For few of the requests there are multiple examples and hence it is necessary for us to add the name of the example to distinguish the example. The issue is as described below.

```
"examples" : {
    "application/json" : { 
        "Response 1 " : {
            "type" : "ABC",
            "version" : "1457566762351",
            "canDo" : false,
            "ignoreWarning" : true,
            "requests" : [ "dsdsdsacfc41f7e" ]
        }
    }
}
```

But in the UI it comes as

```
{
  "Response 1 ": {
    "type": "ABC",
    "version": "1457566762351",
    "canDo": false,
    "ignoreWarning": true,
    "deviceList": [
      "dsdsdsacfc41f7e"
    ]
  }
}
```

It was working fine, when we were using Swagger 2.0 with older jars, when we upgraded the jars to 1.5.8, the above specification stopped working and Example name comes as part of the response body.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I was facing same issue. It seems like they have made a  fix in swagger 3.x. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2651

Comment: [Multiple named examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/) are supported in OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) but not in OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`). What JARs do you mean in "when we upgraded the jars to 1.5.8"? Do you generate the API definition from code annotations? If so, post your source code with annotations instead.

Comment: @Helen We are using custom generation, not from code annotations. We are preparing JSON with the help of multiple resources and hence it is difficult for us to upgrade the swagger to OpenAPI 3.0. Is there any workaround for the same in Swagger 2.0

Comment: @AshutoshSharma is there any way where i can add external link in the swagger, which pops up a model, where i can show the examples with the name. It is very difficult to switch to swgger 3.0 as we have complex way of generating json.

Comment: @SuhasBhat u can use stoplight tool that might help you in that case. 
 https://stoplight.io/

Comment: @AshutoshSharma, sure will look into it :)